# Can't override blueprint function

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I've got BaseCharacter blueprint and blueprint PlayerCharacter with BaseCharacter as parent. I'm trying to override function but child event doesn't get invoked. I create event in child class by clicking functions -> override

Parent class

[image: Parent class]

Child class

[image: Child Class]

Comment: @George this doesn't help because I don't need to call parent function, it's empty, and main issue here is that overrided event isn't invoked, so if I call parent function after not invoked event doesn't solve issue

Comment: Not enough information in the question to understand why it may not be working. Based on your description alone it should work.